# Capturing camera(USB) via D2XX library or OPENCV

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, ftdi, d2xx

I want to write an application(in c++) in order to capture images from a camera which is using in a acquisition system. The camera is connected to a box (acquisition system) and I've found that the chip that is used is FTDI. The chip is located in the box between camera and PC. The camera is connected to this box. A USB cable is connected to a PC and the box. Some other tools are connected to the box which are not important.

Moreover, there is a simple commercial application which is written by MFC and I want to do exactly the same. In the folder of the application there are D2XX driver files(ftd2xx.h, etc) and an information file(*.inf) of the camera.

Also, the camera is not recording video but taking photo in short intervals(<0.1s) and the interval is determined by the acquisition system not the commercial application(the acquisition system detect when camera has to take photo)

Here is my question:

Since the information file of the USB device is provided, could I just utilize the Open-CV lib to capture the camera OR do I have to only use D2XX library?

If I have to use D2XX library in order to read the data, how could I convert the raw data to Image format (in Qt)?

I can't simply write application and test on the device over and over to find the solution since the device is located far from my location and for every test I have to travel this distance. So, I want to make sure that my application will work.

A company from China made the device for us and they won't support it any more :(

Comment: I have used OpenCV to record with a bunch of cameras and it always worked, so I think you should not be forced to use that D2XX stuff. Regarding to the second question, if you use OpenCV to capture, I guess you can easily swap from OpenCV format to Qt format.

Comment: Yeah I know that with OpenCV things would be lot easier :)

Comment: Where is the point so? you can, at least, try if you can capture with OpenCV. I think it will be harder to wait for someone to answer this than going there and try to capture with OpenCV.

Comment: Ok, Next week I'll go and test with OpenCV. But as I've said that the camera take photo in a specific interval. So I think the openCV will be failed to capture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The camera uses a custom communications protocol, it doesn't implement an imaging device class. OpenCV won't see it, neither will any other multimedia library. No matter what, you need to implement that protocol. You can then expose it to OpenCV if you wish.

Comment: I've sniffed the data transfer of USB when a image is read. Now how can I convert the raw data into Image format?

Comment: Also I've found that the ICU type is FT245R and the openCV application didn't worked!

Comment: Approach it as you would a puzzle. That's all that I can tell you.

Comment: That's offtopic here. But if you are struggling, perhaps you should look for a contractor to figure it out for you.

Comment: Since those are data of image file, I have to convert the raw data to image file. Is this gives any hint?

Comment: "those are data of image file" I have no idea what that means. Just because you can store an image in a file doesn't mean much. You can treat `cmd.exe` as an "image" file, print it out on a big canvas and claim it's abstract art...

Answer (score 1):

To convert into image, try this:

```
Mat hwnd2mat(HWND hwnd){

HDC hwindowDC, hwindowCompatibleDC;

int height, width, srcheight, srcwidth;
HBITMAP hbwindow;  // <-- The image represented by hBitmap
cv::Mat src;  // <-- The image represented by mat
BITMAPINFOHEADER  bi;

// Initialize DCs
hwindowDC = GetDC(hwnd);   // Get DC of the target capture..
hwindowCompatibleDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hwindowDC);  // Create compatible DC
SetStretchBltMode(hwindowCompatibleDC, COLORONCOLOR);

RECT windowsize;    // get the height and width of the screen
GetClientRect(hwnd, &windowsize);

srcheight = windowsize.bottom;
srcwidth = windowsize.right;
height = windowsize.bottom *2/ 2;  //change this to whatever size you want to resize to
width = windowsize.right *2/ 2;

src.create(height, width, CV_8UC4);

// create a bitmap
hbwindow = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hwindowDC, width, height);
bi.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);   
bi.biWidth = width;
bi.biHeight = -height;  //this is the line that makes it draw upside down or not
bi.biPlanes = 1;
bi.biBitCount = 32;
bi.biCompression = BI_RGB;
bi.biSizeImage = 0;
bi.biXPelsPerMeter = 0;
bi.biYPelsPerMeter = 0;
bi.biClrUsed = 0;
bi.biClrImportant = 0;

// use the previously created device context with the bitmap
SelectObject(hwindowCompatibleDC, hbwindow);
// copy from the window device context to the bitmap device context
StretchBlt(hwindowCompatibleDC, 0, 0, width, height, hwindowDC, 0, 0, srcwidth, srcheight, SRCCOPY); //change SRCCOPY to NOTSRCCOPY for wacky colors !
GetDIBits(hwindowCompatibleDC, hbwindow, 0, height, src.data, (BITMAPINFO *)&bi, DIB_RGB_COLORS);  //copy from hwindowCompatibleDC to hbwindow

// avoid memory leak
DeleteObject(hbwindow); DeleteDC(hwindowCompatibleDC); ReleaseDC(hwnd, hwindowDC);

return src;
}
```